# How to use the result of a query to do a calculation?

Tags: sql

I have to rerun the same query by just changing the date range.

I have to divide the answer from the queries and get a percentage, like (1/2)*100.

How do I implement this? Here is a query that returns a number:

```
select count(distinct a.ST_NUM) 
          from table2 b, 
               table1 a,
               table 3 c
               where 
         b.VEND_CD in ($vendorCD1)
      and b.ITM_CD_1=($ITMCD)
      and b.area_num=($area)
      and b.area_num= a.area_num
      and b.itm_cd_2 = a.itm_cd_2
      and a.week_end =c.week_end 
      and c.week_end between ($startdate)  and  ($enddate)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since both queries return a single row, you could cross join them:

```
SELECT x / y * 100 AS percent
FROM   (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT a.ST_NUM) AS x
        FROM   table2 b, 
               table1 a,
               table 3 c
        WHERE  b.VEND_CD IN ($vendorCD1) AND
               b.ITM_CD_1 = ($ITMCD) AND
               b.area_num = ($area) AND
               b.area_num = a.area_num AND
               b.itm_cd_2 = a.itm_cd_2 AND
               a.week_end = c.week_end AND
               c.week_end BETWEEN ($startdate) AND ($enddate)) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT a.ST_NUM) AS y
            FROM   table2 b, 
                   table1 a,
                   table 3 c
            WHERE  b.VEND_CD IN ($vendorCD1) AND
                   b.ITM_CD_1 = ($ITMCD) AND
                   b.area_num = ($area) AND
                   b.area_num = a.area_num AND
                   b.itm_cd_2 = a.itm_cd_2 AND
                   a.week_end = c.week_end AND
                   c.week_end BETWEEN ($startdate2) AND ($enddate2)) t2
```

Comment: Thanks Mureinik. When  I run this query, the  result is always a 100 because  I can enter the parameters only once ... while I re rerun the first query I have to change my  startdate and end date.How do I modify this so that I get the prompts for entering  different set of parameters.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @sql_learner like in his query did u changed the parameter name in second query with `2`

Comment: The value returned by this query has to be used in a series of calculations. For example, if the above value is between 50 and 100 rolling value would be xx. If the above value is >100, rolling value would be yy. I understand I need to use a case statement for this... My question is how do I make the value returned by the above query an input to another query which calculates the  rolling value.Thanks for your help.